# Browser Refresh leads to IllegalStateException with Vaadin CDI and ViewScoped beans

Tags: vaadin, cdi

I have a simple Vaadin app in which I use CDI injection. My views are generated with CDIViewProvider and Vaadin-Navigation and everything works fine, even when i inject a @ViewScoped bean (lets say a simple ViewScoped Presenter or a component) in the view.

But in this case when I do a browser refresh, an error is thrown:

```
com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't find proper view for @ViewScoped bean, no views are active for this ui.
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleExceptionDuringRequest(VaadinService.java:1464)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1421)
at com.vaadin.cdi.server.VaadinCDIServletService.handleRequest(VaadinCDIServletService.java:92)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:364)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
```

I currently have no idea why, in my idea a @ViewScoped bean should be initialized when navigated to the view (as it works for the first navigation to the view). Am I missing something? When I change the presenter to @SessionScoped it works, but I want the bean to be destroyed when the user navigates to another view.

Comment: I haven't used CDI because I mainly use Spring, however this seems fishy. Does this happen while the UI is annotated with `@PreserveOnRefresh` as well as when it's not?

Comment: No, when I have @PreserveOnRefresh activated, the error does not appear, as the view instance is still the same I think? But I would want the view to refresh...

Comment: Indeed, the [`@PreserveOnRefresh`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/annotations/PreserveOnRefresh.html) ensure that the app state is preserved on a browser refresh. I found this very useful in UIs that showed a progress bar for longer operations for example. Nonetheless, if you check the API in the link, you'll notice that `Whenever a request is received that reloads a preserved UI, the UI's refresh method is invoked by the framework.` so you can just override the UI's refresh method adding your own implementation. Alternatively, you can provide a dedicate button somewhere on the view.